# Cucumber and TestNG, how to pass parameter?

Tags: testng, cucumber

Could you please tell, how to pass parameter in Cucumber using TestNG?

I have following code, but it does not work.
Error in **stepDefinition.java** on the line `@Parameters({"environment"})`

**testng.xml**

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="Suite">
        <parameter name="environment" value="qa"/>
        <test name="Validating Login Page">
            <classes>
                <class name="cucumberOptions.CucumberRunner"/>
            </classes>
        </test>
    </suite>
```

**CucumberRunner.java**

```java
    @CucumberOptions(
            features = "src/test/java/features",
            glue="stepDefinitions")
    public class CucumberRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    
    }
```

**login.feature**

```java
    Feature: Check Login Page
    
      Scenario: Check Login title
        Given Browser is initialled
        When User opens Login Page
        Then Print current Page title
        And Close browser
```

**stepDefinition.java**

```java
    public class stepDefinition extends TestBase {
    
        @Parameters({"environment"})
        @Given("^Browser is initialled$")
        public void initBrowser(String environment) {
          initialize(environment);
        }
    
        @When("^User opens Login Page$")
        public void userOpensLoginPage() {
            driver.get(url);
        }
    
        @Then("^Print current Page title$")
        public void printCurrentTitle() {
            //some code
        }
    
        @And("^Close browser$")
        public void printCurrentTitle() {
            tearDown();
        }
    }
```

**TestBase.java**

```java
    public class TestBase {
    
        public static WebDriver driver = null;
        public static String url;
    
        public void initialize(String environment) {
            
    
            if(environment.equals("qa")){url = "http://qa.com";}
            else{url = "http://prod.com";}
    
            WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
    
        public void tearDown() {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

**Error:**

```java
    cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Step [^Browser is initialled$] is defined with 1 parameters at 'stepDefinitions.stepDefinition.initBrowser(String) in file:/Users/artur/IdeaProjects/testProject/target/test-classes/'.
    However, the gherkin step has 0 arguments.
    Step text: Browser is initialled
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your question? Which error do you see?

Comment: @AlexeyR. done!

Comment: I believe Cucumber runner ignores what you have in `testng.xml`. It checks your feature file and tries to match it with method signature in your step definition code. Step in feature file does not imply any paramterization, however your step code accepts the parameter. This makes Cucumber to throw exception. How do you run your code?

Comment: I run testng.xml

Comment: Then it seems you have a conflict with how TestNG interprets parameters and how Cucmber treats its part. Why dont you include the env definition to your Given step? like `Given Browser is initiated in QA environment`

Comment: @AlexeyR. But why? If I through Jenkins pass parameter on which env tests should be run. I don't want to write scenario for each env.

Comment: Then you can set your env value as environment variable and use something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531694/how-can-i-get-system-variable-value-in-java in your code. Of course unless you have a proper solution.

Comment: Oddly enough, my code uses the same usage of parameters but spacing might be the problem. It's the only difference I see.  Mine: `@Parameters({ "deviceNumber" })`